# Link_Server data displayed as junk characters when passed from SQL Server to Oracle DB

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm currently having issues executing an Oracle procedure from a SQL Server DB using LINK_SERVER. I'm able to execute the procedure, which involves taking data from the SQL Server DB and inserting it into the Oracle DB. However, for some of the record's values it's inserting the data as "junk characters" (i.e. "䍄䵒吠獥⁴潦⁲乓‣湡⁤䅖呓䤠" instead of "Test Description") and I'm not entirely sure why. We're not using any special characters but, when it's being passed from the SQL Server DB to our Oracle DB it changes the value to these junk characters. Let me know if more information is needed and thanks in advance.

Comment: What character set is being used on your SQL Server database? Same question for Oracle?

Comment: Oracle VARCHAR2, SQL Server varchar

Comment: What is data provider used when setup linked server?

Comment: @Wendy "Oracle Provider for OLE DB"

Comment: `VARCHAR` is not a character set. A character set is the convention used to represent how many bytes a character takes up, and what each code means. For Oracle some examples are US7ASCII, WE8ISO8859P1, JA16SJIS, and AL32UTF8.